# regex replace every 2nd occurrence with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, tags

I would like to replace some keywords to HTML elements in a textarea with javascript.
Is there any way to replace every 2nd string that has been found?

Just for an example what I mean is: if there are 6 `$` signs in the string, the first, third, and fifth would be replaced to  HTML tag and the rest to `</strong>` HTML tag.

Comment: Could you please show example of input string and expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the match and replace in pairs with a capture group between them:

```js
string = 'This is a $word$ and $two words$ and a $phrase with several words$.';
newstring = string.replace(/\$([^$]*)\$/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
console.log(newstring);
```

Comment: Damn. I was SO overcomplicating that, trying to work with lookaheads and lookbehinds and all. Massive props. I want to like this one TWICE!

Comment: Yeah, it's easy to get a mental block if you don't think about things in the right way. You were so focused on the `$`, you didn't think about the phrases.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your answer!!!! I really apprecite that! One more question before I mark it as solution. Between the strong tags, what does the $1 means?

Comment: That gets replaced with the string that was captured by the capture group. Any regexp tutorial will explain this.

Comment: @Roelly, take a look at the MDN article on regex, and search the page for "capturing groups". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Also see this [tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacetutorial.html)